# Can I integrate Airbnb listings with a routeplanner?

Tags: online-resources, planning, accommodation, gps-navigation

I am preparing a road trip this summer. I often use Airbnb to find accommodation. However when on the road finding potential listings in Airbnb can become quite tedious. Is it possible to integrate a given route with nearby Airbnb listings?

Comment: Isn't the problem that airbnb reservations aren't instant (4 hours typical, 24 hours worst case), and aren't confirmed? Would seem to make it hard to book something while on the road for that night...

Comment: @gagravarr It is not about instant finding an airbnb listing. I am preparing a road trip for this summer. I would be nice if I would be able to get all airbnb options along a route.

Comment: So you want to plot a path from say, San Fran to NYC, and show all AirBNBs available along that path??

Comment: @markmayo yep that is the idea

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.  Airbnb doesn't offer that kind of functionality on their site, but the bigger issue is that they won't allow anyone else to do it either.

Why isn't it possible? The reason is that AirBnb is keeping their system tightly closed as isn't providing an "API", which is what other websites need to be able to work with AirBnb to develop websites that work with their data.  For some period of time, they did share their data with HipMunk, but they no longer are.  HipMunk now uses HomeAway data instead of AirBnb.

So there are websites such as http://roadnow.com/ that will let you find hotels along a particular route (using data from TripAdvisor), but for now it isn't possible to do that sort of thing for routes with AirBnb.

As far as possible alternatives, HomeAway (a similar site to AirBnb) does offer an API (see http://www.homeaway.com/platform/developers.html).  But so far no one that I know of has used it to create a tool that lets you find properties along a route.